# JavaScript and JQuery do not work when called from onchange in a select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, html-select

I am new to jquery and javascript, and I have searched for this answer and couldn't find it.

My select tag:

```
<select id="selectarea" name="sometext" size="10" width="250" style="width: 250px" onchange="openDisciplina(this)">
<?php
    foreach ($areas as $name) {
        echo "<option value='" . htmlentities($name[0]) . "'>" . htmlentities($name[0]) . "</option>";
    }
?>
</select><br>
```

and my js function:

```
<script>
function openDisciplina(element)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://arenautfpr.com/professor/stage/disciplina/disciplina.php",
        data: {dados:element.value},
        success: function(data){
            $('#novidades2').html(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

when I call this function it does not work at all, nothing happens. Even if I put only an alert inside the function it won't work, so I don't think it is a problem with the ajax part.

On the error console I get this error when I choose an option:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: openDisciplina

---- SOLVED

I Found that the problem was with the code not being on the `<head>` tag, so it was not working.

Comment: is there an element with id 'novidades2' ? have you checked that the request is well-formed ([fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) may be helpful here)?

Comment: Do you have any errors? And do you mean your `openDisciplina` doesn't work or the AJAX bit?

Comment: The function works well for me.http://jsfiddle.net/Ss9sR/

Comment: @collapsar, there is a div with that id, I'm on a Mac, so fiddler isn't compatible. How can I check that w/o fiddler?

Comment: I edited the post with the error I am receiving on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove the javascript from the select element and use this script:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("body").on( "change", "#selectarea", function() {
        alert("changed");
        //test with alert before putting your code in here
        //jQuery.ajax({
            //type: "POST",
            //url: "relative/path/to/disciplina.php",
            //data: {dados:this.value},
            //success: function(data){
                //$('#novidades2').html(data);
            //}
        //});
    });
});
```

Note that:

- in the ajax call I changed dados to `this.value` instead of `element.value`.
- using relative path instead of absolute path to disciplina.php
- delegation is needed for the event since `#selectarea` is generated dynamically after the dom is loaded. I used delegation from the `body`, but it may be more efficient to delegate from a closer parent element of `#selectarea`.

Comment: Nothing happened. This .php file was already inserted into the page using AJAX, does this make any difference, to try calling functions from inside a document loaded by ajax?

Comment: @JoãoMiranda, Ah... try using delegation: changing `$("#selectarea").change( function() { ...` to `$("body").on("change","#selectarea", function() { ...`

Comment: ok, the alert works now, but when I put the ajax code in it, it does nothing

Comment: It does nothing, I checked the resources section of safari's development console and it is calling the page I request, but it is returned as an empty page and marked in red(I don't know what it means by that).

Comment: @JoãoMiranda, so the success callback isn't even happening... I was thinking possibly it was just not getting any data and that's why you weren't seeing anything get put into novidades2. It seems like you aren't getting a success in your ajax call.

Comment: the file should return the data I posted to it. Just for testing. But it is not reaching the success callback indeed.

Comment: I don't think so, the code in the file is just 
`<h1>
 <?php

 var_dump($_POST);
 
 ?>
 </h1>`
so it should work just fine

Comment: No, it's on the same domain

Comment: it returns a blank statement, am I doing it wrong? `fail(function( x, textStatus, details ) {   alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus + ":" + details ); });`

Comment: I found the solution! I was not putting the scripts inside header, they were in the body so it was not finding them.

Answer (score 0):

Check the error in console.
it not calling because there is some error which is preventing to call this function.

try onchange event handler. here is fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dlinx/y4Ge5/)

```
<select id="selectarea" name="sometext" size="10" >
    <option val=1>One</option>
    <option val=2>Two</option>
    <option val=3>Three</option>
    <option val=4>Four</option>
</select>
<script>
var s=document.getElementById('selectarea');
s.onchange=function(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
<script>
```

And if you want to use previous code only then try to put script block in head of page.

Comment: I edited the post with the error I am receiving on the console